# SAS: Force PROC GCHART to show empty columns

Tags: sas, proc, gchart

I create a chart with `PROC GCHART`. Assume the data looks like this:

```
Month    Volume
Jan      2
Feb      4
May      19
Sep      7
```

When I create the graph with **GCHART** using Month and Volume, I get four bars. I would like to see the entire year though (with empty columns for the remaining months).
I tried using :

```
axis order=('Jan','Feb',...,'Nov','Dec');
```

but still, I only get four columns instead of twelve. What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a dataset that includes the months without data.  Then use that dataset with your AXIS statement to force all months to appear in GCHART.  See the example code below.  Hope this helps.

```
data have;
    infile cards;
    input Month $  Volume;
    cards;
Jan      2
Feb      4
May      19
Sep      7
;
run;


*** CREATE A DATASET WITH ALL 12 MONTHS ***;
data allmon;
    infile cards;
    input Month $ @@;
    cards;
Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
;
run;

*** USE PROC SQL TO MERGE BOTH DATASETS WITHOUT HAVING TO SORT FIRST ***;
*** USE THIS DATASET WITH GCHART ***;
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select *
    from allmon left join have
    on (allmon.month = have.month)
;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;


axis1 order=('Jan' 'Feb'  'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec');

proc gchart data=want;
    vbar month / sumvar=volume maxis=axis1;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually you don't have to create the empty fields. Just using axis, declaring all months, and using maxis works just fine :)